# Combining two (or more) arrays in PHP without keys and no duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, performance, duplicates

I'm running into a problem where I'm trying to merge 2 (or more!) arrays in which the keys are not explicitly defined, and where I'm looking to not have any duplicates. This seems to be a silly problem to have, but I'm struggling to find an efficient way to solve it. Let me illustrate:

```
// for example, here are some arrays, the last 2 are the same...
$one   = array(1);
$two   = array(2);
$three = array(2);
```

Now, ideally I'd like to 'merge' these three arrays to have something like:

```
array(1, 2);
```

Using current PHP ability, this is what I have tried so far:

```
// this produces: array(1, 2, 2)
$merged = array_merge($one, $two, $three);

// this produces: array(2)
$merged = $one + $two + $three;
```

Both of which are not exactly ideal for what I need. Is there something obvious I'm missing? I really don't want to start looping through each array individually to check for duplicates before adding them to a merged array..!

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow up `array_merge` with [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$merged = array_unique(array_merge($one, $two, $three));
```

Note that in the general case this will produce a result where the keys are not a sequence of integers. If that is a problem, reindex on top of that with `array_values($merged)`.

If you are merging *lots* of items and you expect to have a substantial number of duplicates then it may be worth it to explore more efficient alternatives, but don't worry about it preemptively.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but what happens if each array I'm merging into `$merged` is fed in a `foreach` loop for example? Is it efficient enough to run `array_unique` every time I want to merge in another array (potentially hundreds)? Thanks for this! :)

Comment: @ChrisKempen: I was just editing to mention that. It depends really. You could reduce the waste by doing everything manually and inserting items from the inputs **both as keys and values** into a temporary, then `array_flip` the temporary to get the result. There are fine points to look out for but that's the gist. However, I wouldn't worry unless you can definitely prove that the waste hurts you.

Comment: @ChrisKempen: Also, if you need to update the result incrementally then nothing will help with reducing the waste.